# How is the Monero wallet picking outputs for transactions to spend?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, output-selection

It seems like there are a lot of things to take into account for which outputs in a wallet to spend to preserve privacy. Preventing temporal alignments etc. Is there a lot of code for picking? How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of code indeed.

Since you mention temporal alignment, I assume you mean selection of the real outputs (as opposed to fake ones). The code is in src/wallet/wallet2.cpp, and the interesting functions are:

- get_output_relatedness: this returns a score for how much two outputs are thought to be related (ie, same tx, from similar heights...)
- pop_best_value_from: this will pick a new output, trying to keep to outputs which aren't related to ones we already picked
- create_transactions_2: this is the main function, and it creates the transaction(s)

There's an attempt to build a tx with one or two outputs. If this fails, random outputs (unrelated, if possible) will be selected until enough monero is gathered. If a single input is enough, a second one will be used too, if an unrelated one is available, and it will be the smallest (in terms of monero).

That's the general idea. See the code mentioned above for all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the codes to the functions referred to by @user36303 for those who don't know how to access it.

get_output_relatedness:

```
// This returns a handwavy estimation of how much two outputs are related
// If they're from the same tx, then they're fully related. From close block
// heights, they're kinda related. The actual values don't matter, just
// their ordering, but it could become more murky if we add scores later.
float wallet2::get_output_relatedness(const transfer_details &td0, const transfer_details &td1) const
{
  int dh;

  // expensive test, and same tx will fall onto the same block height below
  if (td0.m_txid == td1.m_txid)
    return 1.0f;

  // same block height -> possibly tx burst, or same tx (since above is disabled)
  dh = td0.m_block_height > td1.m_block_height ? td0.m_block_height - td1.m_block_height : td1.m_block_height - td0.m_block_height;
  if (dh == 0)
    return 0.9f;

  // adjacent blocks -> possibly tx burst
  if (dh == 1)
    return 0.8f;

  // could extract the payment id, and compare them, but this is a bit expensive too

  // similar block heights
  if (dh < 10)
    return 0.2f;

  // don't think these are particularly related
  return 0.0f;
}
```

pop_best_value_from:

```
size_t wallet2::pop_best_value_from(const transfer_container &transfers, std::vector<size_t> &unused_indices, const std::list<size_t>& selected_transfers, bool smallest) const
{
  std::vector<size_t> candidates;
  float best_relatedness = 1.0f;
  for (size_t n = 0; n < unused_indices.size(); ++n)
  {
    const transfer_details &candidate = transfers[unused_indices[n]];
    float relatedness = 0.0f;
    for (std::list<size_t>::const_iterator i = selected_transfers.begin(); i != selected_transfers.end(); ++i)
    {
      float r = get_output_relatedness(candidate, transfers[*i]);
      if (r > relatedness)
      {
        relatedness = r;
        if (relatedness == 1.0f)
          break;
      }
    }

    if (relatedness < best_relatedness)
    {
      best_relatedness = relatedness;
      candidates.clear();
    }

    if (relatedness == best_relatedness)
      candidates.push_back(n);
  }

  // we have all the least related outputs in candidates, so we can pick either
  // the smallest, or a random one, depending on request
  size_t idx;
  if (smallest)
  {
    idx = 0;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < candidates.size(); ++n)
    {
      const transfer_details &td = transfers[unused_indices[candidates[n]]];
      if (td.amount() < transfers[unused_indices[candidates[idx]]].amount())
        idx = n;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    idx = crypto::rand<size_t>() % candidates.size();
  }
  return pop_index (unused_indices, candidates[idx]);
}
```

create_transactions_2:

```
// Another implementation of transaction creation that is hopefully better
// While there is anything left to pay, it goes through random outputs and tries
// to fill the next destination/amount. If it fully fills it, it will use the
// remainder to try to fill the next one as well.
// The tx size if roughly estimated as a linear function of only inputs, and a
// new tx will be created when that size goes above a given fraction of the
// max tx size. At that point, more outputs may be added if the fee cannot be
// satisfied.
// If the next output in the next tx would go to the same destination (ie, we
// cut off at a tx boundary in the middle of paying a given destination), the
// fee will be carved out of the current input if possible, to avoid having to
// add another output just for the fee and getting change.
// This system allows for sending (almost) the entire balance, since it does
// not generate spurious change in all txes, thus decreasing the instantaneous
// usable balance.
std::vector<wallet2::pending_tx> wallet2::create_transactions_2(std::vector<cryptonote::tx_destination_entry> dsts, const size_t fake_outs_count, const uint64_t unlock_time, uint32_t priority, const std::vector<uint8_t> extra, bool trusted_daemon)
{
  std::vector<size_t> unused_transfers_indices;
  std::vector<size_t> unused_dust_indices;
  uint64_t needed_money;
  uint64_t accumulated_fee, accumulated_outputs, accumulated_change;
  struct TX {
    std::list<size_t> selected_transfers;
    std::vector<cryptonote::tx_destination_entry> dsts;
    cryptonote::transaction tx;
    pending_tx ptx;
    size_t bytes;

    void add(const account_public_address &addr, uint64_t amount, bool merge_destinations) {
      std::vector<cryptonote::tx_destination_entry>::iterator i;
      i = std::find_if(dsts.begin(), dsts.end(), [&](const cryptonote::tx_destination_entry &d) { return !memcmp (&d.addr, &addr, sizeof(addr)); });
      if (!merge_destinations || i == dsts.end())
        dsts.push_back(tx_destination_entry(amount,addr));
      else
        i->amount += amount;
    }
  };
  std::vector<TX> txes;
  bool adding_fee; // true if new outputs go towards fee, rather than destinations
  uint64_t needed_fee, available_for_fee = 0;
  uint64_t upper_transaction_size_limit = get_upper_tranaction_size_limit();
  const bool use_rct = use_fork_rules(4, 0);

  const uint64_t fee_per_kb  = get_per_kb_fee();
  const uint64_t fee_multiplier = get_fee_multiplier(priority, get_fee_algorithm());

  // throw if attempting a transaction with no destinations
  THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(dsts.empty(), error::zero_destination);

  // calculate total amount being sent to all destinations
  // throw if total amount overflows uint64_t
  needed_money = 0;
  for(auto& dt: dsts)
  {
    THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(0 == dt.amount, error::zero_destination);
    needed_money += dt.amount;
    LOG_PRINT_L2("transfer: adding " << print_money(dt.amount) << ", for a total of " << print_money (needed_money));
    THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(needed_money < dt.amount, error::tx_sum_overflow, dsts, 0, m_testnet);
  }

  // throw if attempting a transaction with no money
  THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(needed_money == 0, error::zero_destination);

  // gather all our dust and non dust outputs
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m_transfers.size(); ++i)
  {
    const transfer_details& td = m_transfers[i];
    if (!td.m_spent && (use_rct ? true : !td.is_rct()) && is_transfer_unlocked(td))
    {
      if ((td.is_rct()) || is_valid_decomposed_amount(td.amount()))
        unused_transfers_indices.push_back(i);
      else
        unused_dust_indices.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  LOG_PRINT_L2("Starting with " << unused_transfers_indices.size() << " non-dust outputs and " << unused_dust_indices.size() << " dust outputs");

  // early out if we know we can't make it anyway
  // we could also check for being within FEE_PER_KB, but if the fee calculation
  // ever changes, this might be missed, so let this go through
  THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(needed_money > unlocked_balance(), error::not_enough_money,
      unlocked_balance(), needed_money, 0);

  if (unused_dust_indices.empty() && unused_transfers_indices.empty())
    return std::vector<wallet2::pending_tx>();

  // start with an empty tx
  txes.push_back(TX());
  accumulated_fee = 0;
  accumulated_outputs = 0;
  accumulated_change = 0;
  adding_fee = false;
  needed_fee = 0;
  std::vector<std::vector<tools::wallet2::get_outs_entry>> outs;

  // for rct, since we don't see the amounts, we will try to make all transactions
  // look the same, with 1 or 2 inputs, and 2 outputs. One input is preferable, as
  // this prevents linking to another by provenance analysis, but two is ok if we
  // try to pick outputs not from the same block. We will get two outputs, one for
  // the destination, and one for change.
  LOG_PRINT_L2("checking preferred");
  std::vector<size_t> prefered_inputs;
  uint64_t rct_outs_needed = 2 * (fake_outs_count + 1);
  rct_outs_needed += 100; // some fudge factor since we don't know how many are locked
  if (use_rct && get_num_rct_outputs() >= rct_outs_needed)
  {
    // this is used to build a tx that's 1 or 2 inputs, and 2 outputs, which
    // will get us a known fee.
    uint64_t estimated_fee = calculate_fee(fee_per_kb, estimate_rct_tx_size(2, fake_outs_count + 1, 2), fee_multiplier);
    prefered_inputs = pick_preferred_rct_inputs(needed_money + estimated_fee);
    if (!prefered_inputs.empty())
    {
      string s;
      for (auto i: prefered_inputs) s += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + "(" + print_money(m_transfers[i].amount()) + ") ";
      LOG_PRINT_L1("Found prefered rct inputs for rct tx: " << s);
    }
  }
  LOG_PRINT_L2("done checking preferred");

  // while:
  // - we have something to send
  // - or we need to gather more fee
  // - or we have just one input in that tx, which is rct (to try and make all/most rct txes 2/2)
  while ((!dsts.empty() && dsts[0].amount > 0) || adding_fee || should_pick_a_second_output(use_rct, txes.back().selected_transfers.size(), unused_transfers_indices, unused_dust_indices)) {
    TX &tx = txes.back();

    LOG_PRINT_L2("Start of loop with " << unused_transfers_indices.size() << " " << unused_dust_indices.size());
    LOG_PRINT_L2("unused_transfers_indices:");
    for (auto t: unused_transfers_indices)
      LOG_PRINT_L2("  " << t);
    LOG_PRINT_L2("unused_dust_indices:");
    for (auto t: unused_dust_indices)
      LOG_PRINT_L2("  " << t);
    LOG_PRINT_L2("dsts size " << dsts.size() << ", first " << (dsts.empty() ? -1 : dsts[0].amount));
    LOG_PRINT_L2("adding_fee " << adding_fee << ", use_rct " << use_rct);

    // if we need to spend money and don't have any left, we fail
    if (unused_dust_indices.empty() && unused_transfers_indices.empty()) {
      LOG_PRINT_L2("No more outputs to choose from");
      THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(1, error::tx_not_possible, unlocked_balance(), needed_money, accumulated_fee + needed_fee);
    }

    // get a random unspent output and use it to pay part (or all) of the current destination (and maybe next one, etc)
    // This could be more clever, but maybe at the cost of making probabilistic inferences easier
    size_t idx;
    if ((dsts.empty() || dsts[0].amount == 0) && !adding_fee) {
      // the "make rct txes 2/2" case - we pick a small value output to "clean up" the wallet too
      std::vector<size_t> indices = get_only_rct(unused_dust_indices, unused_transfers_indices);
      idx = pop_best_value(indices, tx.selected_transfers, true);

      // we might not want to add it if it's a large output and we don't have many left
      if (m_transfers[idx].amount() >= m_min_output_value) {
        if (get_count_above(m_transfers, unused_transfers_indices, m_min_output_value) < m_min_output_count) {
          LOG_PRINT_L2("Second output was not strictly needed, and we're running out of outputs above " << print_money(m_min_output_value) << ", not adding");
          break;
        }
      }

      // since we're trying to add a second output which is not strictly needed,
      // we only add it if it's unrelated enough to the first one
      float relatedness = get_output_relatedness(m_transfers[idx], m_transfers[tx.selected_transfers.front()]);
      if (relatedness > SECOND_OUTPUT_RELATEDNESS_THRESHOLD)
      {
        LOG_PRINT_L2("Second output was not strictly needed, and relatedness " << relatedness << ", not adding");
        break;
      }
      pop_if_present(unused_transfers_indices, idx);
      pop_if_present(unused_dust_indices, idx);
    } else if (!prefered_inputs.empty()) {
      idx = pop_back(prefered_inputs);
      pop_if_present(unused_transfers_indices, idx);
      pop_if_present(unused_dust_indices, idx);
    } else
      idx = pop_best_value(unused_transfers_indices.empty() ? unused_dust_indices : unused_transfers_indices, tx.selected_transfers);

    const transfer_details &td = m_transfers[idx];
    LOG_PRINT_L2("Picking output " << idx << ", amount " << print_money(td.amount()) << ", ki " << td.m_key_image);

    // add this output to the list to spend
    tx.selected_transfers.push_back(idx);
    uint64_t available_amount = td.amount();
    accumulated_outputs += available_amount;

    // clear any fake outs we'd already gathered, since we'll need a new set
    outs.clear();

    if (adding_fee)
    {
      LOG_PRINT_L2("We need more fee, adding it to fee");
      available_for_fee += available_amount;
    }
    else
    {
      while (!dsts.empty() && dsts[0].amount <= available_amount)
      {
        // we can fully pay that destination
        LOG_PRINT_L2("We can fully pay " << get_account_address_as_str(m_testnet, dsts[0].addr) <<
          " for " << print_money(dsts[0].amount));
        tx.add(dsts[0].addr, dsts[0].amount, m_merge_destinations);
        available_amount -= dsts[0].amount;
        dsts[0].amount = 0;
        pop_index(dsts, 0);
      }

      if (available_amount > 0 && !dsts.empty()) {
        // we can partially fill that destination
        LOG_PRINT_L2("We can partially pay " << get_account_address_as_str(m_testnet, dsts[0].addr) <<
          " for " << print_money(available_amount) << "/" << print_money(dsts[0].amount));
        tx.add(dsts[0].addr, available_amount, m_merge_destinations);
        dsts[0].amount -= available_amount;
        available_amount = 0;
      }
    }

    // here, check if we need to sent tx and start a new one
    LOG_PRINT_L2("Considering whether to create a tx now, " << tx.selected_transfers.size() << " inputs, tx limit "
      << upper_transaction_size_limit);
    bool try_tx;
    if (adding_fee)
    {
      /* might not actually be enough if adding this output bumps size to next kB, but we need to try */
      try_tx = available_for_fee >= needed_fee;
    }
    else
    {
      size_t estimated_rct_tx_size;
      if (use_rct)
        estimated_rct_tx_size = estimate_rct_tx_size(tx.selected_transfers.size(), fake_outs_count, tx.dsts.size() + 1);
      else
        estimated_rct_tx_size = tx.selected_transfers.size() * (fake_outs_count+1) * APPROXIMATE_INPUT_BYTES;
      try_tx = dsts.empty() || (estimated_rct_tx_size >= TX_SIZE_TARGET(upper_transaction_size_limit));
    }

    if (try_tx) {
      cryptonote::transaction test_tx;
      pending_tx test_ptx;

      needed_fee = 0;

      LOG_PRINT_L2("Trying to create a tx now, with " << tx.dsts.size() << " destinations and " <<
        tx.selected_transfers.size() << " outputs");
      if (use_rct)
        transfer_selected_rct(tx.dsts, tx.selected_transfers, fake_outs_count, outs, unlock_time, needed_fee, extra,
          test_tx, test_ptx);
      else
        transfer_selected(tx.dsts, tx.selected_transfers, fake_outs_count, outs, unlock_time, needed_fee, extra,
          detail::digit_split_strategy, tx_dust_policy(::config::DEFAULT_DUST_THRESHOLD), test_tx, test_ptx);
      auto txBlob = t_serializable_object_to_blob(test_ptx.tx);
      needed_fee = calculate_fee(fee_per_kb, txBlob, fee_multiplier);
      available_for_fee = test_ptx.fee + test_ptx.change_dts.amount + (!test_ptx.dust_added_to_fee ? test_ptx.dust : 0);
      LOG_PRINT_L2("Made a " << ((txBlob.size() + 1023) / 1024) << " kB tx, with " << print_money(available_for_fee) << " available for fee (" <<
        print_money(needed_fee) << " needed)");

      if (needed_fee > available_for_fee && dsts[0].amount > 0)
      {
        // we don't have enough for the fee, but we've only partially paid the current address,
        // so we can take the fee from the paid amount, since we'll have to make another tx anyway
        std::vector<cryptonote::tx_destination_entry>::iterator i;
        i = std::find_if(tx.dsts.begin(), tx.dsts.end(),
          [&](const cryptonote::tx_destination_entry &d) { return !memcmp (&d.addr, &dsts[0].addr, sizeof(dsts[0].addr)); });
        THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(i == tx.dsts.end(), error::wallet_internal_error, "paid address not found in outputs");
        if (i->amount > needed_fee)
        {
          uint64_t new_paid_amount = i->amount /*+ test_ptx.fee*/ - needed_fee;
          LOG_PRINT_L2("Adjusting amount paid to " << get_account_address_as_str(m_testnet, i->addr) << " from " <<
            print_money(i->amount) << " to " << print_money(new_paid_amount) << " to accomodate " <<
            print_money(needed_fee) << " fee");
          dsts[0].amount += i->amount - new_paid_amount;
          i->amount = new_paid_amount;
          test_ptx.fee = needed_fee;
          available_for_fee = needed_fee;
        }
      }

      if (needed_fee > available_for_fee)
      {
        LOG_PRINT_L2("We could not make a tx, switching to fee accumulation");

        adding_fee = true;
      }
      else
      {
        LOG_PRINT_L2("We made a tx, adjusting fee and saving it");
        do {
          if (use_rct)
            transfer_selected_rct(tx.dsts, tx.selected_transfers, fake_outs_count, outs, unlock_time, needed_fee, extra,
              test_tx, test_ptx);
          else
            transfer_selected(tx.dsts, tx.selected_transfers, fake_outs_count, outs, unlock_time, needed_fee, extra,
              detail::digit_split_strategy, tx_dust_policy(::config::DEFAULT_DUST_THRESHOLD), test_tx, test_ptx);
          txBlob = t_serializable_object_to_blob(test_ptx.tx);
          needed_fee = calculate_fee(fee_per_kb, txBlob, fee_multiplier);
          LOG_PRINT_L2("Made an attempt at a  final " << ((txBlob.size() + 1023)/1024) << " kB tx, with " << print_money(test_ptx.fee) <<
            " fee  and " << print_money(test_ptx.change_dts.amount) << " change");
        } while (needed_fee > test_ptx.fee);

        LOG_PRINT_L2("Made a final " << ((txBlob.size() + 1023)/1024) << " kB tx, with " << print_money(test_ptx.fee) <<
          " fee  and " << print_money(test_ptx.change_dts.amount) << " change");

        tx.tx = test_tx;
        tx.ptx = test_ptx;
        tx.bytes = txBlob.size();
        accumulated_fee += test_ptx.fee;
        accumulated_change += test_ptx.change_dts.amount;
        adding_fee = false;
        if (!dsts.empty())
        {
          LOG_PRINT_L2("We have more to pay, starting another tx");
          txes.push_back(TX());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (adding_fee)
  {
    LOG_PRINT_L1("We ran out of outputs while trying to gather final fee");
    THROW_WALLET_EXCEPTION_IF(1, error::tx_not_possible, unlocked_balance(), needed_money, accumulated_fee + needed_fee);
  }

  LOG_PRINT_L1("Done creating " << txes.size() << " transactions, " << print_money(accumulated_fee) <<
    " total fee, " << print_money(accumulated_change) << " total change");

  std::vector<wallet2::pending_tx> ptx_vector;
  for (std::vector<TX>::iterator i = txes.begin(); i != txes.end(); ++i)
  {
    TX &tx = *i;
    uint64_t tx_money = 0;
    for (size_t idx: tx.selected_transfers)
      tx_money += m_transfers[idx].amount();
    LOG_PRINT_L1("  Transaction " << (1+std::distance(txes.begin(), i)) << "/" << txes.size() <<
      ": " << (tx.bytes+1023)/1024 << " kB, sending " << print_money(tx_money) << " in " << tx.selected_transfers.size() <<
      " outputs to " << tx.dsts.size() << " destination(s), including " <<
      print_money(tx.ptx.fee) << " fee, " << print_money(tx.ptx.change_dts.amount) << " change");
    ptx_vector.push_back(tx.ptx);
  }

  // if we made it this far, we're OK to actually send the transactions
  return ptx_vector;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) but it doesn't seem to work...